# What does it mean 0.1" w.c. to 20" w.c.?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, adc

It is in a Dwyer series 607 datasheet ( Low Range Differential Pressure Transmitter).

Comment: It would help if you would give some context, like quoting the paragraph or sentence it appears in.

Answer (score 4):

Water column, in inches. You could have found it in a few seconds with Google.